# How to change the scanning area of a zxing qr-scanner using BarcodeView

Tags: java, cordova, cordova-plugins, zxing, barcode-scanner

I'm using zxing to scan QR codes and show a camera preview using the Barcodeview class. As of now, the scanner works great if the QRCode is in the exact middle of the camera preview. However, if the QR code is placed in an area of preview that's not the middle it does not scan:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/htVOk.jpg

Here is the relevant code:

Getting the BarcodeView:

```
cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
 @Override
 public void run() {
 // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
 mBarcodeView = new BarcodeView(cordova.getActivity());

 //Configure the decoder
 ArrayList<BarcodeFormat> formatList = new ArrayList<BarcodeFormat>();
 formatList.add(BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE);
 mBarcodeView.setDecoderFactory(new DefaultDecoderFactory(formatList, null, null));

 //Configure the camera (front/back)
 CameraSettings settings = new CameraSettings();
 settings.setRequestedCameraId(getCurrentCameraId());
 mBarcodeView.setCameraSettings(settings);

 FrameLayout.LayoutParams cameraPreviewParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
 ((ViewGroup) webView.getView().getParent()).addView(mBarcodeView, cameraPreviewParams);

 cameraPreviewing = true;
 webView.getView().bringToFront();

 mBarcodeView.resume();
 }
 });
```

And scan:

```
this.nextScanCallback = callbackContext;
final BarcodeCallback b = this;
this.cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
       if (mBarcodeView != null) {
          mBarcodeView.decodeSingle(b);
       }
    }
});
```

If the above code isn't sufficient, the whole project can be found [here](https://github.com/willhay/cordova-plugin-qrscanner/blob/feature/android-platform/src/android/QRScanner.java)

I'm trying to make it so the qr code can be detected in any portion of the camera preview, not just the middle. Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Similar issue here: https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner/issues/130 I'm not using a CameraManager class so I can't change those values to increase the scanning area.

Comment: Anybody have an idea?